# iphone - How can I referencing a UILabel from a custom table cell (dynamic)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, storyboard, uilabel

I created a UITableView in Storyboard.

For the prototype cell, I use custom cell and added 3 UILabel onto it.

The question is when I want to update the content for the 3 UILabel, how can I get the references of them?

Thanks

Comment: Get main view and then drill down, or alternatively just create `IBOutlet` and connect them from your storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to assign tags to the labels in storyboard.  Then, when you have the cell and need the label - like in cellForRowAtIndexPath - you can do this:

```
UILabel *myLabel0 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:kMY_LABEL0_TAG];
UILabel *myLabel1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:kMY_LABEL1_TAG];
```

and so on, where you've #defined those constants to match the tags in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom UITableViewCell and set the UILabels as properties.  You can then access the cells through the table view.